# loops and data file

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, excel

I have solved a set of equations for a specific given data point and restricted my solutions to 100. then I did `TrimmedMean` to have the mean value of all 100 solutions. I need to do the same for different given data points which are all in an excel file but don't know how I put them in a loop to get 100 solutions for each set of given data.
I used the first row of this table as given data:

```
f             Rp    Tp
1.8*10^(12) 0.133   0.601
1.9*10^(12) 0.127   0.608
2.0*10^(12) 0.121   0.612
2.4*10^(12) 0.113   0.617
```

and this is my code for the first row:

```
d = 2/100;
f = 1.8*10^(12);
c = 3*10^(8);
lambda = c/f;
alpha = Exp[-2*Pi*k*d/lambda];
delta = 4*Pi*n*d/lambda;
R = ((n - 1)^2 + k^2)/((n + 1)^2 + k^2);
Rp = 0.133;
Tp = 0.601;

pts = Table[
   FindRoot[{
      R (1 + (alpha)^4 - 2*(alpha)^2*Cos[delta])/(1 - 2*(alpha)^2*R*Cos[delta] + (alpha)^4*R^2) == Rp,
      ((alpha)^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 2*(alpha)^2*R*Cos[delta] + (alpha)^4*R^2) == Tp
     },
    {n, RandomReal[{1.5, 1.7}]}, {k, RandomReal[{0, 0.02}]}],
  {1000}];
TrimmedMean[n /. pts]
TrimmedMean[k /. pts]
```

I need to do the same for all other rows and finally plot all Trimmed `n`'s and `k`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code into a function that takes `{f,Rp,tp}` as an argument, outputs your trimmed values and then use `Map` or maybe `ParallelMap` to evaluate this function for all input values. Use `Import` with proper settings to get a matrix where `{f,Rp,tp}` are stored in the rows. How to do this is for instance shown [in this HowTo](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportASpreadsheet.html)

```
ClearAll[trim,vals];
(* let list be of the form {f,Rp,Tp} *)
trim[list_] :=
  Module[
   {d, f, c, alpha, delta, lambda, k, n, Tp, Rp, R, pts},
   f = list[[1]];
   Rp = list[[2]];
   Tp = list[[3]];
   d = 2/100;
   f = 1.8*10^(12);
   c = 3*10^(8);
   lambda = c/f;
   alpha = Exp[-2*Pi*k*d/lambda];
   delta = 4*Pi*n*d/lambda;
   R = ((n - 1)^2 + k^2)/((n + 1)^2 + k^2);
   pts = Table[
     FindRoot[{R (1 + (alpha)^4 - 2*(alpha)^2*Cos[delta])/(1 - 
            2*(alpha)^2*R*Cos[delta] + (alpha)^4*R^2) == 
        Rp, ((alpha)^2*(1 - R)^2)/(1 - 
           2*(alpha)^2*R*Cos[delta] + (alpha)^4*R^2) == Tp}, {n, 
       RandomReal[{1.5, 1.7}]}, {k, RandomReal[{0, 0.02}]}], {1000}];
   {TrimmedMean[n /. pts], TrimmedMean[k /. pts]}
   ];
```

I have manually rewritten your input data (as said, use `Import` to get it as a matrix):

```
vals = {{1.8*10^(12), 0.133, 0.601}, {1.9*10^(12), 0.127, 0.608}, {2.0*10^(12), 0.121, 0.612}, {2.4*10^(12), 0.113, 0.617}};
```

Now use `Map` (`/@`) to get the desired output:

```
trim[#] & /@ vals
(* {{1.62331, 0.000223783}, {1.61242, 0.000221324}, {1.60573, 0.000221825}, {1.60296, 0.000222526}} *)
```

Please note that there is a bunch of warnings. However, this approach does what you requested. If you have a very big amount of input settings it might indeed be worth to use `ParallelMap` to gain some speedup.

**Remark about `Import` and `ParallelTable`**

From your OP I guess that your .xlsx file looks like this

[image]

Then you can `Import` your data as follows:

```
vals = Import["/path/to/file.xlsx"][[1, 2 ;;]]
(* {{1., 2., 3.}, {4., 5., 6.}, {7., 8., 9.}} *)
```

where the `Part` `[[1,2;;]]` mainly removes the headline which labels your columns. With that you are able to use the code presented above. As already mentioned in my comment, you may want to try `ParallelMap[trim[#]&,vals]` as well and check its speed (`AbsoluteTiming[]`) compared to the single-kernel `Map` approach that I have used above (for enough input data it might improve speed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It helped me a lot. As I have a very big excel file to import, you mentioned it's better use ParallelMap instead, but don't know how use it!

Comment: @Ela Just run `ParallelMap[trim[#]&,vals]`. Use `AbsoluteTiming` to see how fast both versions are on your machine. Also, as you mention that my answer helped you a lot, you might consider upvoting/accepting it

Comment: I tried to upvote but it's saying I need to earn 15 reputation then my vote will be considered. In this code whenever I manually input data, it perfectly works out but when I use:vals=Import["myexcelfile.xlsx"] it doesn't. It perfectly reads my excel file and output is like {f,Rp,Tp} but doesn't work in this form!

Comment: I tried to upvote but it's saying I need to earn 15 reputation then my vote will be considered. In this code whenever I manually input data, it perfectly works out but when I use:vals=Import["myexcelfile.xlsx"] it doesn't. It perfectly reads my excel file and output is like {f,Rp,Tp} but doesn't work in this form!

Comment: @Ela Please see my updated answer. Does it now explain everything you need?

Comment: Hi, I am using your help on another problem that the different columns are complex variables, but Mathematica cannot work in the same way. I am not sure if its problematic cause I am using complex numbers or the code itself.Basically, I have 4 columns of the complex number in my excel file and want to solve 3 linear equations to find 3 complex unknowns.